# Android - Help needed in solving Layout inconsistancy (RelativeLayout and LinearLayout)

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am building an app with a reusable numeric keyboard. The keyboard has been placed in its own XML file so it can be included where needed throughout the app. I want to split the screen for the current activity into two pieces, the fixed size numeric keyboard at the bottom and a RelativeLayout (RL) above with the rest of the controls.

The problem is, the RL isn't behaving itself. In the example below, the RL takes up the entire screen, and the keyboard does not show. The really strange thing is when I reverse the placement, place the include with the keyboard at the top, the screen displays as expected, with keyboard and RL each taking up roughly half.

In other words: when the keyboard is included at the top, all is fine (but the keyboard is in the wrong place); but when I include the keyboard at the bottom, the keyboard does not show and the RL takes up the entire screen.

Help! This kind of inconsistency drives me nuts and I am on the verge of hurling the computer across the room.

The activity's XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/statsTabLayout"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="#ffffff" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:baselineAligned="true" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/statsTopLayout"
        android:background="#ffffff" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewTopMargin" 
        android:text="                              " 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize = "5sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingTop="0px"
    ></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewAverage" 
        android:text="Average =    (%)" 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize = "25sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTopMargin"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ></TextView>

    <Button android:id="@+id/buttonReset" 
        android:text="reset" 
        android:onClick="resetButtonClick" 
        android:textSize = "12sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewAverage" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewAverage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTopMargin"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    ></Button>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewHi" 
        android:text="High= " 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize = "20sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewAverage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewLow" 
        android:text="Low= " 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize = "20sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewAverage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    ></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewMax" 
        android:text="Max= " 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize = "20sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewAverage"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    ></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewScore" 
        android:text="Score = " 
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:textSize = "30sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewScoreCalculation"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewScoreCalculation" 
        android:text="(score calculation)" 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize = "20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10px"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextPoints"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    ></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewPoints" 
        android:text="Enter Points: " 
        android:textSize = "30sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewBottomMargin"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10px"
    ></TextView>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/editTextPoints" 
        android:text="" 
        android:digits="-0123456789."
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textSize = "30sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewPoints" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewPoints"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewBottomMargin"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewPoints" 
        android:paddingBottom="10px"
    ></EditText>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewBottomMargin" 
        android:text="                              " 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize = "5sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:paddingBottom="0px"
    ></TextView>


    </RelativeLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/numerickeyboard" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The parent layout for the included keyboard:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="104pt" 
    android:id="@+id/numberPadLayoutContainer" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#404040"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that some of the child layout attributes for `RelativeLayout`, such as `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, require that the layout decide its own dimensions before laying out the child that wants to align to its Bottom. In effect, when the child asks to alignParentBottom, it forces the RelativeLayout to use all the vertical space available to it.

The last several items in your layout stack above the final element, `TextView android:id="@+id/textViewBottomMargin"`, which is defined as `alignParentBottom`. I fixed the layout by modifying those last few elements to align below the previous items instead of aligning above the last item.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/statsTabLayout"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="#ffffff" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:baselineAligned="true" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/statsTopLayout"
        android:background="#ffffff" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewTopMargin" 
        android:text="                              " 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize = "5sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingTop="0px"
    ></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewAverage" 
        android:text="Average =    (%)" 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize = "25sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTopMargin"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ></TextView>

    <Button android:id="@+id/buttonReset" 
        android:text="reset" 
        android:onClick="resetButtonClick" 
        android:textSize = "12sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewAverage" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewAverage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTopMargin"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    ></Button>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewHi" 
        android:text="High= " 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize = "20sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewAverage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewLow" 
        android:text="Low= " 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize = "20sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewAverage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    ></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewMax" 
        android:text="Max= " 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize = "20sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewAverage"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    ></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewScore" 
        android:text="Score = " 
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:textSize = "30sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewHi"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewScoreCalculation" 
        android:text="(score calculation)" 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize = "20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewScore"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    ></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewPoints" 
        android:text="Enter Points: " 
        android:textSize = "30sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewScoreCalculation"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10px"
    ></TextView>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/editTextPoints" 
        android:text="" 
        android:digits="-0123456789."
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textSize = "30sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewPoints" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewPoints"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewPoints" 
        android:paddingBottom="10px"
    ></EditText>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewBottomMargin" 
        android:text="                              " 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize = "5sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextPoints"
        android:paddingBottom="0px"
    ></TextView>


    </RelativeLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/numerickeyboard" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I also modified the keyboard by removing its `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` statement.

This is the screenshot op an HVGA_1.6 emulator (I made your keyboard area green for the screenshot).

[image]

**As per the amended question, "also want the statsTopLayout to fill the screen when we don't include the keyboard" (see comments)**, I humbly submit these modifications to the original main and keyboard layout files:

In the original `main.xml`, change the root `LinearLayout` to a `RelativeLayout`, then move the `<include>` to be its first element. In that moved `<include>` element, add the `android:id="@+id/numberPadLayoutContainer"` statement from `numerickeyboard.xml` (and remove it from `numerickeyboard.xml` (`main.xml` won't compile without the local ID declaration). The third element is now the enclosed `RelativeLayout`, which now specifies `layout_height="fill_parent"` and `layout_above="@id/numberPadLayoutContainer"`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/statsTabLayout"
    android:background="#ffffff" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    >

    <include layout="@layout/numerickeyboard" 
            android:id="@+id/numberPadLayoutContainer" 
        />

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/statsTopLayout"
        android:background="#ffffff" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_above="@id/numberPadLayoutContainer">


    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewTopMargin" 
        android:text="                              " 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize = "5sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingTop="0px"
    ></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewAverage" 
        android:text="Average =    (%)" 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize = "25sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTopMargin"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ></TextView>

    <Button android:id="@+id/buttonReset" 
        android:text="reset" 
        android:onClick="resetButtonClick" 
        android:textSize = "12sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewAverage" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewAverage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTopMargin"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    ></Button>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewHi" 
        android:text="High= " 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize = "20sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewAverage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewLow" 
        android:text="Low= " 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize = "20sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewAverage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    ></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewMax" 
        android:text="Max= " 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize = "20sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewAverage"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    ></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewScore" 
        android:text="Score = " 
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:textSize = "30sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewScoreCalculation"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewScoreCalculation" 
        android:text="(score calculation)" 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize = "20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10px"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextPoints"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    ></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewPoints" 
        android:text="Enter Points: " 
        android:textSize = "30sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewBottomMargin"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10px"
    ></TextView>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/editTextPoints" 
        android:text="" 
        android:digits="-0123456789."
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textSize = "30sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewPoints" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewPoints"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewBottomMargin"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewPoints" 
        android:paddingBottom="10px"
    ></EditText>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewBottomMargin" 
        android:text="                              " 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize = "5sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:paddingBottom="0px"
    ></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Screenshot with the `<include>` statement:

[image]

Screenshot without the `<include>` statement and without the `android:layout_above="@id/numberPadLayoutContainer"` statement:

[image]

Comment: This is nice, but I am not sure it is the solution I am looking for. The relative layout containing the top controls was added to allow separation. The average/hi/lo/max on top, score/score cal in the middle and point entry at the bottom. That would allow the app to re-size itself naturally when used on larger phones and tablets. The solution you suggest will cluster the controls at the top leaving a large blanks space on larger phones and tabs.

Comment: So, the question is again, how do I add the RelativeLayout at the top, and the keyboard (also a RelativeLayout) at the bottom, while allowing the controls to be placed as if it was the only layout on the screen?

Comment: I edited the answer to provide a solution for your amended question.

Comment: That is it exactly. With this fix, adjusting the screen for different phones and tabs should only be a matter of setting the font size. Thank you. I'm still not sure why your solution worked, but my original did not; nor am I sure why including the keyboard first should make a difference. But those are questions for another day... I hear my bed calling. :-)

Comment: Oh, and thank you for the detailed answer, especially with the screen grabs. A lot of the time the answers are short, cryptic, and with partial or no examples. It was a great help for me, and I am sure it will help anyone stumbling across this question in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help; tell your friends. BTW, you aren't supposed to be able to refer to IDs that are defined farther down in the XML -- I was surprised that it worked. I put the `<include>` up top out of habit since I was referring to its ID in the next element.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that when you put the keyboard layout at the bottom, it is being rendered off screen.  You can easily see if that is the case by putting your entire layout into a ScrollView.

I would also suggest you specify the layout_height of the keyboard using dp not pt values.  Otherwise, it might not look correct across various screen densities.

Comment: I agree, I'm fairly certain that the keyboard is being rendered off screen. The question is how do I get it to stop doing it. How do I get the statsTopLayout to play nice and share the physical screen with the keyboard.

Comment: Oh, and the Pt value for the keyboard is irrelevant as it is re-sized dynamically when the app is run. This dynamic resizing is why it is important that the rest of the layout play nice and act as advertized.